# mesh disappear when I go to texture paint

Tags: uv, edit-mode, texture-painting

whenever I go to texture paint tab my mesh disappears?
I Apply UV Editing To My Mesh also
Any Help please, thanks in advance [image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stay in *Solid* mode while texture painting, it will display the selected image on the surface of the object, for the moment the selected image (*skin tone*) is transparent, so your character appears transparent. Here is where you select the image in Blender 4 (it was previously in the N panel):

[image]

You either need to switch to *Material* preview, or if you stay in *Solid* mode choose another image. Also note that the unwrap is messy, you should re-unwrap, you can choose the *Smart UV Project* option for example.

Comment: i wonder how i missed that , thank you for ur help

Comment: I guess because the way the Solid mode displays in Texture Paint is a bit unexpected   ;)